# Access to Google's blacklists for my firewall

Tags: firewall, blacklist

I know that certain google products automatically access Google's blacklist database. Can I do the same? Is there maybe a cleaned-up dns server against which I could verify my own dns queries? Or some Webservice I could use?

I have a linux firewall, so I can do almost anything programmatically.

Comment: You can do the same if you work for Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent, yes.  [Google opened up their malware blacklist by making the Safe Browsing API publicly available, and you can signup here](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/key_signup?csw=1).

That is, however, the only one I'm aware of them exposing to the public for free.